# summation over array slower than summing individual variables in Julia

Tags: arrays, performance, sum, julia

Ok, I'm doing a serie of tests lately. I have a MC simulation where I have several variables (20) which make sense to put them all inside a one-dimensional array because it makes several things easier to read.

But I'm having one problem, I need to sum the variables in every iteration and the simulation takes A LOT of iterations, so I run into this problem (reduced to 7 variables):

```
function sumtest1(N)
    s=0.0
    a=1.0
    b=2.0
    c=3.0
    d=4.0
    e=5.0
    f=6.0
    g=7.0
    for i = 1:N
        s += (a+b+c+d+e+f+g)
    end
    return s
end

function sumtest2(N)
    s=0.0
    A=[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0]
    for i = 1:N
        s += sum(A)
    end
    return s
end

@time sumtest1(1_000_000_000)
elapsed time: 0.998272756 seconds (96 bytes allocated)

@time sumtest1(1_000_000_000)
elapsed time: 7.522198967 seconds (208 bytes allocated)
```

Is this expected? Or am I doing something wrong? I would really like to have my variables indexed because of other reasons too long to explain now, but this performance penalty is something I can't go with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at the LLVM code that's being executed for `sumtest1`:

```
julia> @code_llvm sumtest1(10^9)

define double @julia_sumtest1_21391(i64) {
top:
  %1 = icmp sgt i64 %0, 0
  %2 = select i1 %1, i64 %0, i64 0
  %3 = icmp eq i64 %2, 0
  br i1 %3, label %L3, label %L.preheader

L.preheader:                                      ; preds = %top
  %4 = icmp sgt i64 %0, 0
  %smax = select i1 %4, i64 %0, i64 0
  br label %L

L:                                                ; preds = %L, %L.preheader
  %lsr.iv = phi i64 [ %smax, %L.preheader ], [ %lsr.iv.next, %L ]
  %s.0 = phi double [ %5, %L ], [ 0.000000e+00, %L.preheader ]
  %5 = fadd double %s.0, 2.800000e+01
  %lsr.iv.next = add i64 %lsr.iv, -1
  %6 = icmp eq i64 %lsr.iv.next, 0
  br i1 %6, label %L3, label %L

L3:                                               ; preds = %L, %top
  %s.1 = phi double [ 0.000000e+00, %top ], [ %5, %L ]
  ret double %s.1
}
```

That's pretty hard to grok, but one thing stands out in the body of the loop, `L`:

```
  %5 = fadd double %s.0, 2.800000e+01
```

For each iteration, the pre-computed constant `28.0` is being added to the accumulator, `s`. The compiler can tell that you never change any of the local variables and so it knows that the same sum is being added every time. The only reason that the loop has to execute at all is that repeated floating-point addition is not exactly equivalent to multiplication. If all the local variables are changed to integers, where repeated addition is exactly equivalent to multiplication, the loop is eliminated entirely:

```
julia> @time sumtest1_int(10^9)
  0.000005 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
28000000000

julia> @code_llvm sumtest1_int(10^9)

define i64 @julia_sumtest1_int_21472(i64) {
top:
  %1 = icmp slt i64 %0, 1
  br i1 %1, label %L3, label %L.preheader

L.preheader:                                      ; preds = %top
  %2 = icmp sgt i64 %0, 0
  %.op = mul i64 %0, 28
  %3 = select i1 %2, i64 %.op, i64 0
  br label %L3

L3:                                               ; preds = %L.preheader, %top
  %s.1 = phi i64 [ 0, %top ], [ %3, %L.preheader ]
  ret i64 %s.1
}
```

Which translates roughly back into Julia as:

```
sumtest1_int(N) = N < 1 ? 0 : ifelse(N > 0, N*28, 0)
```

That's a little redundant, since the body could be simplified to `ifelse(N > 1, N*28, 0)` (which could in turn be changed to just `28N` since we don't care about negative values of `N`), but it's still much faster than executing a loop.

The function `sumtest2` cannot be analyzed or optimized nearly so easily. It would require proving that the array `A` can never be changed, which is quite difficult. So the compiler has no choice but to do all the work, which is, of course, much slower than not doing it. In your simulation, it may still be faster to use local variables than storing values in an array, but it may not. You'll have to measure code that does something harder to optimize away completely to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, it's very informative and I'm learning a lot. I realized that by trying to simplify the function to post it here, I trivialized it like you explained. The real situation is that at least 1 (usually more) of the variables change in each iteration, none is constant. Would the situation be different in that case? I will test it out and post the findings later.

Comment: No problem. It is unlikely that the compiler can do this kind of optimization if anything remotely non-trivial changes in the loop. Local variables will still have advantages over slots in arrays: an array needs to be stored in memory somewhere; local variables can live in CPU registers.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tested it by simply generating a single random number `r` inside the loop and sum it to each local variable in the first function, and the time went from 1 sec to 6 secs... which is still faster than the original second function without even generating the random number... It kinda blows because I had some ideas of sorting the variables to increase the speed of some other calculations, which I don't know how to do if the variables are local. But oh well, will keep studying. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: You can sort a fixed number of local variables with a small set of explicit comparisons and swaps.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski I've tried `sumtest1` in several Julia version and none got to do this multiplication optimization (they did manage to reduce the loop to adding 28.0 each time). Does your Julia still do this? If yes, which version are you using?