# is there a way to obtain a collection pointing to variables in Julia?

Tags: pointers, collections, julia, local-variables

Lets assume I have 3 variables R1, R2 and R3. I'd like to have a Dictionary (or other collection) that point to the variables, so that if I modify the variable it also changes the value in the Dictionary.

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
R1 = 0.0
R2 = 0.0
R3 = 0.0

D = Dict(1=>R1, 2=>R2, 3=>R3)

D[1]
output> 0.0

R1 = 1.0

D[1]
output> 1.0
```

Is there a way to do this in Julia?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you just need a standard Julia array?

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Yes... but I want to try not using one, for the reasons explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801197/summation-over-array-slower-than-summing-individual-variables-in-julia I don't if it's possible to do what I want to do, but worth giving it a try

Comment: `Dict` will be many times slower than an array.

Comment: @FengyangWang It was, thanks for the answer anyway. Will have to think on another way of doing this :/

Answer (score 7):

You can make them `Ref`s:

```
R1 = Ref(0.0)
R2 = Ref(0.0)
R3 = Ref(0.0)

D = Dict(1=>R1, 2=>R2, 3=>R3)

D[1][]  # output> 0.0

R1[] = 1.0

D[1][]  # output> 1.0
```

`Ref`s are like pointers. The syntax for assigning into them is `ref[] = x`, and the syntax for getting their value is `ref[]`. So just make sure you don't forget the `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just use a mutable object and mutate it instead of assigning over it. e.g.

```
R1 = [0.];
R2 = [0.];
R3 = [0.];
D = Dict(1=>R1, 2=>R2, 3=>R3);
D[1] #> 0.0
R1[1] = 1.  # or just R1[] = 1. since empty brackets reference first element
D[1] #> 1.0
```